# Integrate KML on offline Google Map iOS

Tags: ios, google-maps, swift4, kml, offline

I want to create a kml file programmatically in iOS Swift4. I surfed a lot regarding **offline** GoogleMaps & saving data in kml file, but I haven't found any relevant material regarding this. In short, I just want to store some POI in kml & display it in **offline** Googlemap!!

Answer (score 0):

KML is an XML document scheme. You can write it in any way you see fit. Use a dedicated XML encoder or brute force using strings.

The full spec is documented at https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference

You may find examining existing KML files useful to show example structures.

Here is an example brute force encoder to encode a set of labeled placemarks…

Raw strings will need to be XML escaped before writing to file.

You may find [Google Toolbox for Mac](https://github.com/google/google-toolbox-for-mac/blob/master/Foundation/GTMNSString%2BXML.m) useful here.

```
class KMLWriter {

 func createKMLFormat(_ logs:[DDBLogEntry])->String {

        var kml = preamble()

        for log in logs {
            kml += placemarkForLog(log)
        }

        terminate(&kml)

        return kml
    }

    func placemarkForLog(_ log:DDBLogEntry)->String {

        let name = log.userContent ?? "empty"
        let time = log.dateCreated ?? Date()
        let timeStamp = Date.UTCDateFormatter.string(from: time)

        return "<Placemark>\n<name>\(name)</name>\n<Point><coordinates>\(log.longitude ?? 0),\(log.latitude ?? 0),\(log.elevation ?? 0)</coordinates></Point>\n<TimeStamp><when>\(timeStamp)</when></TimeStamp>\n</Placemark>\n"

    }


    func preamble()->String {

        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n<kml xmlns=\"http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2\">\n<Document>\n"

    }

    func terminate(_ kml:inout String) {

        kml += "</Document>\n</kml>\n"

    }

}
```

Comment: Does this file help to create dynamic kml file?

Comment: It helps me create a KML file for my use case which is to output a set of placemarks. I don't know what you want to do.

Comment: I just want to create Kml file. Store some POI in kml  & display it in offline google map!! Can u please share whole code regarding this?

Comment: I did. KML is XML, XML is a text file. Generate string and save it. That’s what I showed you.

Comment: Can you plz share the whole code? Because I'm facing unknown identifiers error!!